# How to have ember-couchdb-kit pull data from a view

Tags: ember.js, couchdb

I have an Ember application backed by CouchDB. Currently, my default route is:

```
App.ReadingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend( {
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find( 'reading' )
  }
} )
```

This pull entries from the `all` view. I would like to switch it to `by_time`, but I'm uncertain how to specify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out digging through the code:

```
return this.store.findQuery( 'reading', {
  designDoc: 'reading',
  viewName: 'by_time',
  options: {
    descending: true
  }
} )
```